# Grammar of calculator in a finite field

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, bison

I have a working calculator apart from one thing: unary operator '-'.

It has to be evaluated and dealt with in 2 difference cases:

1. When there is some expression further like so -(3+3)
2. When there isn't: -3

For case 1, I want to get a postfix output 3 3 + -
For case 2, I want to get just correct value of this token in this field, so for example in Z10 it's 10-3 = 7.

My current idea:

```
E:  ...
    |   '-' NUM %prec NEGATIVE      { $$ = correct(-yylval); appendNumber($$);          }
    |   '-' E %prec NEGATIVE        { $$ = correct(P-$2); strcat(rpn, "-");                                 }
    |   NUM     { appendNumber(yylval); $$ = correct(yylval); }
```

Where NUM is a token, but obviously compiler says there is a confict reduce/reduce as E can also be a NUM in some cases, altough it works I want to get rid of the compilator warning.. and I ran out of ideas.

Comment: `E can also be a NUM in some cases` - right, so why do you even need that first rule?

Comment: Because I have to do different things in case there is just the token NUM after '-' and different when there is a whole expression after '-'

Comment: Edited the code to make the difference clearer

Comment: For case 2, why not just have the same rpn output?  (ie: 3 - ).  You get this by just deleting the first rule.

Comment: Because the -(2+2) wouldn't be recognizable.

Comment: Recognisable to whom? The RPN for that would be `2 2 + -`. What's unrecognisable about that? And the RPN for case 2 is `3 -`. Simple. The cases are not distinct.

Comment: The cases are distinct, because in RPN instead of '3 -' I would write (for example field Z10) 7 (because 10-3 = 7) while if it's after expression like -(2+2) i just write 2 2 + -.

Comment: By what rule? Isn't that just a rule for negative results? Rather than a rule for unary minus literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It has to be evaluated and dealt with in 2 difference cases:

No it doesn't. The cases are not distinct.

Both `- E` and `- NUM` are incorrect. The correct grammar would be something like:

```
primary
    : NUM
    | '-' primary
    | '+' primary /* for completeness */
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;
```

Comment: They are distinct in my use case as you can see in the question.

Comment: No, I can't see it from your question. All I can see is inconsistency, which surprises me in someone who knows about finite fields.

Comment: I was just trying to be smart and implement three things at once but I asked the professor and he said it would be impossible or had to be badly written to be that way, so.. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this should be implemented as two rules (pseudocode, I don't know bison syntax):

This is the likely rule for the 'terminal' element of an expression. Naturally, a parenthesized expression leads to a recursion to the top rule:

```
Element => Number
           | '(' Expression ')'
```

The unary minus (and also the unary plus!) are just on one level up in the stack of productions (grammar rules):

```
Term =>    '-' Element
           | '+' Element
           | Element
```

Naturally, this can unbundle into all possible combinations such as `'-' Number`, `'-' '(' Expression ')'`, likewise with `'+'` and without any unary operator at all.

Suppose we want addition / subtraction, and multiplication / division. Then the rest of the grammar would look like this:

```
Expression => Expression '+' MultiplicationExpr
              | Expression '-' MultiplicationExpr
              | MultiplicationExpr

MultiplicationExpr => MultiplicationExpr '*' Term
                      | MultiplicationExpr '/' Term
                      | Term
```

---

*For the sake of completeness:*

Terminals:

- `Number`

Non-terminals:

- `Expression`
- `Element`
- `Term`
- `MultiplicationExpr`

`Number`, which is a terminal, shall match a regexp like this `[0-9]+`. In other words, it **does not** parse a minus sign — it's always a positive integer (or zero). Negative integers are *calculated* by matching a `'-' Number` sequence of tokens.

Comment: Can you add something to it? I know that I can differentiate between " '-' TOKEN" and "TOKEN" but I have to differentiate at one level above, '" '-' TOKEN"' and '" '-' EXPRESSION"'. Something like.. 'if expression == token' would be great

Comment: A token is a token, not an expression. Will expand my answer a bit.

Comment: I know, what I am trying to say is that for me " - EXPRESSION " has two different values based on if expression is actual expression or just a single token.

Comment: Well that's embedded in the lower-level production. What's wrong with such design?

Comment: I don't see how this design would work, `'-' Element` would still be responsible for both ` - TOKEN ` and ` - EXPRESSION ` while if it's token I have to stop parsing and don't let it to to lower production, because it's just a special case of number.

Comment: I'm starting to think you are seeing a non-existent problem. `Number` just *never* contains a `-` sign itself. There's no ambiguity in the grammar I outlined. This is how expression parsing *works* in real compilers and it's inline with mathematical rules.

Comment: @adaPlease It's not a special case of anything. It's a unary minus. Grammars for this abound. You don't need to reinvent this wheel. It was solved in about 1959.